# ASP.NET with disabled button having duplicate postbacks

Tags: asp.net, postback, duplication

I have an asp.net page that allows credit card information and a payment amount to be entered to authorize a payment. All of the sudden about 2 weeks ago, we started getting reports of double charges but we had not made any changes to the page. The page was already set up to disable the submit button upon being clicked. In trying to resolve the problem, I've since also set a flag on the page when the button is clicked so that if the flag is set, it won't allow the button to postback (this is the method we use on another page that has no problems), but it continues to happen.

There's a few reasons why I'm considering the user refreshing the page to be an extremely unlikely source of the problem. First, we display the page in a WPF web browser control, it matches the window its in, and the only indication that it's even a webpage is the clicking noise of postbacks, if you were to right click on the body, or if there were a page error. The only refresh or back buttons are in the browser's context menu. Next, I can think of no motive for users to want to refresh or go back unless they were to receive a page error, but they report receiving no errors in the process. Finally, I took measures to avoid duplicate postbacks on the server side by placing an token in session and checking for it before processing the card. So the user would have to refresh and hit the "Retry" button faster than the first request could write the token to session state. The fastest way to achieve that would be press submit, F5, Enter all in a row. I hate to ignore the only way I know it could happen, but it seems safe to say this isn't what's happening. Finally, upon posting back the page signals the WPF app, via a scripting object, that it can close so the user isn't able to do anything on the page after a postback before the browser disappears.

The only problem is, I don't know what is happening. Somehow a submission just got past the javascript safe guard and the server side token safe guard and got double charged and I have no idea how. They were logged as happening within 2 seconds of each other. I've verified that our WPF app's code isn't calling Refresh or otherwise controlling navigation of the browser. Anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE
Here is some of the relevant code:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        ...
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function OnProcessing(button) //
        {
            //Check if client side validation passes before disabling

            // if postback - return false. If it's 1, then it's a postback.
            if (document.getElementById("<%=HFSubmitForm.ClientID %>").value == '1') {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                // mark that submit is to be done and return true
                document.getElementById("<%=HFSubmitForm.ClientID %>").value = '1';
                button.disabled = true;
                window.external.OnPaymentProcessing();
                return true;
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body id="body" runat="server" style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;" scroll="no" onkeydown="return CancelEnterKey(event)">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:scriptmanager>
        <script src="Resources/Scripts/CardInput.js?<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

        <div id="divCardSwiper" style="text-align:center;" runat="server">
            <input id="txtSwipeTarget" type="text" onblur="FocusOnSwipeTarget()" onkeydown="return SwipeTargetCharAdded(event)"
                    style="position: absolute; left: -1000px" />
            <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                        <span style="font-size: 20pt; font-weight: bold; color: #808080">Please Swipe Credit Card</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td style="text-align:center"><img alt="Card Swiper Image" src="Resources/scra-magnesafe-mini-3.png"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; color: #808080">Or <a href="#" onclick="ManualEntry();return false;">click here</a> to enter manually.</span></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="divCcForm" runat="server">
            <table>
                <!-- Input Fields -->
            </table>
            <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"  ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server"
                Text="Process" OnClick="btnProcess_Click" OnClientClick="if (OnProcessing(this)==false){return false;}" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
                <p><strong>Processing may take a moment.<br><font color="red">PLEASE ONLY CLICK PROCESS ONCE</font></strong></p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HFRequestToken" runat="server"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HFSubmitForm" runat="server"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

```
    protected void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsProcessing())
        {
            //Payment was already processing
            btnProcess.Enabled = false; //Make sure button doesn't become available again
            logger.Warn(String.Format("PaymentCollection.aspx was submitted multiple times. Only processing the initial request (Session Token: {0}). FacilityID: {1}, FamilyID: {2}, Amount: {3}",
                                                Session[_postBackTokenKey], ViewState[_facilityIDKey], ViewState[_familyIDKey], txtAmount.Text));
            return;
        }

        lblError.Text = String.Empty;
        string script = "window.external.OnPaymentProcessingCancelled()";
        bool isRefund = (bool)ViewState[_isRefundKey];
        bool processed = false;

        if (ValidateForm(isRefund))
        {
            ProcessingInput pi = new ProcessingInput();

            try
            {
                CreditCardType cardType = (CreditCardType)Int32.Parse(ddlCardType.SelectedValue);

                pi.CreditCardNumber = txtCardNum.Text.Trim();
                pi.ExpirationMonth = Int32.Parse(ddlExpMo.SelectedValue);
                pi.ExpirationYear = Int32.Parse(ddlExpYr.SelectedValue);
                pi.FacilityID = new Guid(ViewState[_facilityIDKey].ToString());
                pi.FamilyID = new Guid(ViewState[_familyIDKey].ToString());
                pi.NameOnCard = txtName.Text.Trim();
                pi.OrderID = Guid.NewGuid();
                pi.PaymentType = cardType.ToMpsPaymentType();
                pi.PurchaseAmount = Math.Abs(Decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text));
                pi.Cvc = txtCvc.Text.Trim();
                pi.IsCardPresent = cbCardPresent.Checked;


                if (pi.PurchaseAmount >= 0.01m)
                {
                    MerchantProcessingClient svc = new MerchantProcessingClient();

                    try
                    {
                        ProcessingResult result;

                        logger.Debug("Processing transaction (Session Token: {0}) for Facility: {1}, Family: {2}, Purchase Amount{3}",
                                            Session[_postBackTokenKey], pi.FacilityID, pi.FamilyID, pi.PurchaseAmount);

                        if (!isRefund)
                            result = svc.AuthorizePayment(pi);
                        else
                            result = svc.RefundTransaction(pi);

                        if (result.Approved)
                        {
                            //Signal Oasis that it can continue
                            StringBuilder scriptFormat = new StringBuilder();
                            scriptFormat.AppendLine("window.external.OrderID = '{0}';");
                            scriptFormat.AppendLine("window.external.AuthCode = '{1}';");
                            scriptFormat.AppendLine("window.external.AmountCharged = {2};");
                            scriptFormat.AppendLine("window.external.SetPaymentDateFromBinary('{3}');");    //Had to script Int64 as string or it caused an overflow exception for some reason
                            scriptFormat.AppendLine("window.external.CcLast4 = '{4}';");
                            scriptFormat.AppendLine("window.external.SetCreditCardType({5});");
                            scriptFormat.AppendLine("window.external.CardPresent = {6};");
                            scriptFormat.AppendLine("window.external.OnPaymentProcessed();");

                            script = String.Format(scriptFormat.ToString(), result.OrderID, result.AuthCode, result.TransAmount, result.TransDate.ToBinary(),
                                                         (result.MaskedCardNum == null ? String.Empty : result.MaskedCardNum.Replace("*", "")), (int)cardType,
                                                         pi.IsCardPresent.ToString().ToLower());

                            processed = true;   //Don't allow processing again
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //log and display errors
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //log, email, and display errors
                    }
                }
                else
                    lblError.Text = "Transaction Amount is zero or too small to process.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log, e-mail, and display errors
            }
        }

        this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PaymentApprovedScript", script, true);

        //Session[_isProcessingKey] = processed;  //Set is processing back to false if there was an error
        if (!processed)
            Session[_postBackTokenKey] = null;   //Clear postback token if there was an error to allow re-submission
    }

    private bool IsProcessing()
    {
        bool isProcessing = false;
        Guid postbackToken = new Guid(HFRequestToken.Value);

        // This won't prevent simultaneous POSTs because the second could read the value from 
        // session before the first writes it to session. It will help eliminate duplicate posts
        // if the user is messing with the back button or refreshing.
        if (Session[_postBackTokenKey] != null && (Guid)Session[_postBackTokenKey] == postbackToken)   
            isProcessing = true;
        else
            Session[_postBackTokenKey] = postbackToken;

        return isProcessing;
    }
```

Comment: The user clicks Back in the browser and resubmits the postback?

Comment: Thanks Roman. I forgot to mention that javascript notifies the WPF app that it can close the window upon posting back so the user would have to time it perfectly. Pressing the backspace key would make that a little more likely that the refresh option, but combined with the sudden wave of occurrences and frequency (almost once a day, sometimes more) also makes this seem unlikely doesn't it?

Comment: Can we see some of the relevant code?  ASPX markup and any Javascript, VB/C#..

Comment: I've updated the original post with some code. Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised this does not work (if your "HFRequestToken.Value" values are the same across the duplicates?) but why do that at all? Would you ever want more than one transaction active in a session? e.g. why not just say `Session["TransactionActive"] = true`. Session is already keyed to each users' session. As per my answer it does not address true race conditions but I'd be surprised if the requests were coming that fast. I bet IsProcessing is not working.

Comment: Somehow the thought process I went through originally made it seem safer to have a value coming from the client, but you're right that putting a flag in Session would be just as good. IsProcessing works when I test it, but since a duplicate made it through, it's either not working correctly, or there really was a race condition. If it's a race, it seems more likely the source of the problem is not directly caused by user actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having something like this happen once (though not with credit cards). Unfortunately I don't remember what caused it - but I feel as if it was browser-related and not in my control, e.g. something in certain browsers was causing double submits without the user even realizing it.

But the solution is to handle this situation in a race-condition-safe way. Even if there's no reason why (for example) an automated process should or should be operating against your page, assume it could be. Maybe someone is using a plug-in form filler that autosubmits? Or maybe they just have a buggy add-in of some kind, or a mouse with a bad contact on the left button. Seems odd, but who knows what the end-user could be doing that might unknowingly circumvent any client-side protections you have.

Assume that someone can hit your post URL twice in a row (or 100 times in a row). Because, in fact, no matter what client-side protections you have, they could. Don't worry about the client. Instead, on the server, before starting the transaction, get a thread-safe lock, set a flag associated with their session that indicates a transaction is already in progress, and exit if that flag is found.

If you can't trust a session for some reason, then just verify that the data is unique before starting.

(edit per comment) If you change to a situation where you have more than one SQL server responsible for session management (or, just generally, you have no absolute way to get a guaranteed lock with conventional means) then you should jump for joy that you're making so much money, and hire an expert to solve this problem for you :) In the meantime, don't worry about that unless that's truly a problem you will face sometime soon.

At a simple level here's how I would do it (with a single web server). It sounds like you may already know how to do this but anyway...

```
public class MakeMoney() {

    private static object locker=new Object();

    public void DoTransaction(SaleData data) {
        lock(locker) {
            if (SessionLocked) {
                throw new Exception("Already in progress");
                /// or just exit however you want
            }
            LockSession();
        }    

        Profit();

        UnlockSession();
    }
}
```

The implementation of `LockSession`, `UnlockSession`, and `SessionLocked` just have to do with the environment. With one server, `Session` or `HttpContext.Cache` are probably fine. Even if there are multiple servers involved, you could create a single non-distributed server that is only responsible for providing locks -- even a high volume web site (unless you're making millions of sales per minute!) should be able to deal with having just that on a single server.

Scaleability is a concern -- but if you implement it in any reasonably encapsulated way, it should be a piece of cake to swap out the controller for managing locks, should you ever find yourself in that glorious situation.

Comment: This makes sense fundamentally. In practice though, I'm not sure how to do it. I had written some code to place a Semaphore in session (I actually had another thread about this recently) and using that to prevent duplicate postbacks. Then I started thinking about scalability; if we were to change to SQL session, or use multiple servers for load balancing, it would no longer work. I'd be intersted to hear more implementation-specific ideas you might have.

Are plug-ins/add-ins enabled in the WPF wrapped IE active X browser?

Comment: I am not sure about the WPF wrapped comment (that is, I have no idea what you're talking about :) but see edits for a little more detail on implementation.

Comment: You mentioned buggy [browser] plug-ins/add-ins which made me curious if the [WPF WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx), which wraps an IE ActiveX control, has add-ins and plug-ins enabled in it.

Thanks for the example. I wasn't sure lock/monitor would work because of the stateless nature of asp.net. What I mean is the first postback will create an instance of MakeMoney and the second postback will create a separate instance of MakeMoney. I thought the locked code was locked only within the instance it was locked in. Is it not?

Comment: Static members of a class are always single instance - so the static `locker` object is guaranteed to be current. So even though you could have two `DoTransaction` calls in two different instances of the class itself, only one will be able to get the lock on `locker` -- the 2nd one will be queued until the lock is released. This ensures that checking the session lock is up to date. This is just to be 100% sure there is no race condition, but since you're dealing with web requests it's almost unnecessary (but.. for a couple lines of code why not do it right and sleep better?).

Comment: ... what I mean by "almost unnecessary" is the need to get a thread lock with `locker` and not the need to lock the session. Of course you need that or we wouldn't be here :) but the chances of a thread race condition in the few milliseconds it takes to get a session lock are probably very low when the source of the requests is from another computer on the internet.

Comment: Of course...that makes sense. That should make it impossible to get a duplicate so I'll try it out. I'll still have the mystery of how this is happening, but I'm not sure how to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: The only problem with handling it on the server side is the response from the original POST never makes it back to the client (when you throw the exception or otherwise exit). That also poses a problem for me because my code is meant to use the response to record history of the payment.

Comment: "when you throw the exception or otherwise exit" I don't understand why you would care (or even expect) that the client would get a response to an aborted transaction. If it's a duplicate, you want to ignore it don't you? If it was aborted, then why would you want to record it? I also don't understand how this connects with your client architecture anyway - you certainly should not be doing any housekeeping from the client. There are many unrelated reasons the client might fail to get the response after a successful trans. If you track payment histories, why isn't that done at the server?

Comment: I want the response to the transaction that was _not_ aborted. From what I've seen it only actually receives the response to the aborted transaction. Trust me, I hate this design, but using a webpage to handle card data satisfied PCI compliance (arguably) at a fraction of the cost. It connects to the client because the client is the application. The webpage's job is only to authorize a credit card and report back success or failure. I think to really be safe, we'd need a server-side queue that the client can check rather than depending on the page response. Thanks for working with me on this.

Comment: Oh I see - you are saying that because of the browser-intiated double post it's no longer waiting for the first (presumably aborted) request. So instead of just bailing out, exit gracefully with the same response code you would no matter what, except of course you haven't done anything. In effect treat it exactly as if the end-user had clicked "refresh" and sent a duplicate of the post.

Comment: .. let me add that if there's a transaction in progress, you will need to wait for it to finish.

Comment: I think that is pretty much the best we can do. But rather than returning a normal response (which would include some additional transaction information that we wouldn't have), I'll probably return a response with an error code for this scenario and come up with a way for the application to handle it.

Comment: I ended up implementing the submit button using WPF. The user clicks the button, it programatically submits the webpage form and at the same time starts a background process that polls a web service for a response. When the webpage finishes, whatever its result is, it writes its result to a server side database and the client side polling process picks that result up. That way there are no server-to-client communication dependencies and I'm safe in all scenarios.